Patterns in Integration by Parts?
I learned about integration by parts recently and I was interested in the topic of cyclical functions (eg. $e^x$, $\sin,\cos,-\sin,-\cos $). Doing integration by parts when both functions inside the integral were cyclical, I noticed some patterns and wondered if there are any rules/formulas for integrals with two cyclical functions. I created a formula for double-cyclical-function (only with nested functions with degree of 1) integrals and wanted to see if there was a more applicable and extensive (for any degree) formula.
Also, does my formula work?
$\displaystyle{\left(\frac{{\left(\frac{d}{{\left.{d}{x}\right.}}{\left({b}{\left({x}\right)}\right)}\right)}^{2}}{{\left(\frac{d}{{\left.{d}{x}\right.}}{\left({a}{\left({x}\right)}\right)}\right)}^{2}}\right)}{\left({\left( f{{\left({a}{\left({x}\right)}\right)}}\cdot\int g{{\left({b}{\left({x}\right)}\right)}}{\left.{d}{x}\right.}\right)}+{\left(\frac{1}{{\frac{d}{{\left.{d}{x}\right.}}{\left({b}{\left({x}\right)}\right)}}}\right)}^{2}{\left(\frac{d}{{\left.{d}{x}\right.}}{\left( f{{\left({a}{\left({x}\right)}\right)}}\right)}\cdot{\left( g{{\left({b}{\left({x}\right)}\right)}}\right)}\right)}\right)}$

When you say $-\sin$ do you mean $\sin^{-1}$?

I just mean the "loop" of sinx derivatives: sinx, cosx, -sinx, -cosx

Formulas usually come in the form of an equation. There are all sorts of expressions like this that one can create, but they are just algorithms for calculating something. There is no "work" or "doesn't work" unless you make some claim about the thing it calculates. You've got some wild expression here, but what is the point of it?
